# How to display Deepin Screenshot toolbar in Gnome3?

Tags: settings

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Gnome3 on one PC and on the other PC with xfce. The screenshot tool Deepin should display a toolbar after capturing a ROI (region of interest) screenshot with options.

I can see it under Xubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04/xfce).

Under Gnome, I do not see the toolbar. Bug or feature and how to enable the toolbar?

Deepin version is in both cases `5.0.0-1build1`.

[Manual](https://wiki.deepin.org/index.php?title=Deepin_Screenshot&language=en):

> While capturing screenshots, you can click on the icons on the toolbar
> to complete various operations. Run Deepin Screenshot and select the
> screenshot area with the mouse, the toolbar will automatically appear
> below the screenshot area.